# Глюк отрисовки ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

В обработчике окна `Loaded` создаю `ComboBox` и добавляю его в `Grid` окна. При запуске приложения `ComboBox` отрисовывается неправильно (рис. 1) и отображается так пока не наведу на него мышь (рис. 2).

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить, оставив создание и добавление `ComboBox` в обработчике `Loaded`?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"> 
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" />
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = new ComboBox { Width = 100, Margin = new Thickness(50) };
    mainGrid.Children.Add(comboBox);

    comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 1" });
    comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 2" });
    comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 3" });

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Upd:** Как сделать, что бы установка `SelectedIndex` сразу выбирала указанный элемент?

Comment: Попробуйте операцию `Children.Add` перенести в самый конец кода, после выбора `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: Это весь код? Никаких больше событий не обрабатываете?

Comment: Да, это весь код в отдельно созданном пустом проекте

Comment: Может, сделать refresh окна ?

Comment: `comboBox.UpdateLayout();`
`mainGrid.UpdateLayout();`
`UpdateLayout();`
не помогли

Comment: `InvalidateArrange()`, `InvalidateMeasure()`, `InvalidateVisual()` у каждого контрола тоже не помогли

Comment: А покажите полный XAML окна.

Comment: <Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" />
</Window>

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что выбранный айтем не отображается в комбобоксе до тех пор, пока не наведешь мышь. Из-за этого комбобокс сплющивается, а за ним сплющивается и окно. Если убрать `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, то можно будет увидеть окно нормального размера и комбобокс без текста выбранного айтема.

Выбранный айтем отображается только если `SelectedIndex` устанавливается вне события `Loaded` (например, в конструкторе окна или в обработчике нажатия кнопки) или если в событии `Loaded` в качестве айтемов добавляются строки, а не элементы управления. Если честно, это выглядит как баг WPF'а и вполне может проявляться только на определенных версиях фреймворка/ОС.

Comment: Очевидно, что вопрос все таки почему не показывается выбранный айтем!  В моем случае он может быть любым FrameworkElement. Текст, картинка, кнопка, видео, таблица - да что угодно, не в этом суть.

Comment: Данный "ответ" не является ответом. Это всего лишь способ уйти от поставленного вопроса. Вопрос до сих пор не решен и все еще актуален.

Comment: @Vitaliy обновил ответ, но, увы, без результатов.

Answer (score 0):

У меня все скомпилировалось без проблем, возможно на отрисовку элементов влияют подключаемые пространства имен, хотя может все зависит от версии. Я компилировал на Visual Studio 2015 sp3

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" />
</Window>

using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = new ComboBox { Width = 100, Margin = new Thickness(50) };
            mainGrid.Children.Add(comboBox);

            comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 1" });
            comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 2" });
            comboBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Item 3" });

            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая у вас ОС, версия фреймворка, версия проекта?

Comment: Windows 10.0.10586, Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 14.0.25424.00 Update 3, проект .NET 4.5, фреймворк v4.0.30319